# Calendar event in the past no showing

Tags: solspace-calendar

I'm using Solspace Calendar and this code for showing single events...

```
{exp:calendar:events event_id="{segment_3}"}
```

and it works find for showing events in the future, however for past events it's showing No Results.

The past entry status are Open and there is no expiration date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to display **upcoming or past events**, you should use `{exp:calendar:cal}` instead of other Calendar tags. `{exp:calendar:cal}` is the only tag that will display event data in a chronological way. With this tag, the following tag would display events from 1 month past to now:

```
{exp:calendar:cal
    date_range_start="1 month ago"
    date_range_end="today"
    pad_short_weeks="n"
}
```

(You could throw in an `event_id=""` in there as well if needed to limit the list to an event) 
More details about why {exp:calendar:cal} is the tag to use for chronological data can be found here (**Recommended read**):
http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/getting_started/

*Quick summary*: `{exp:calendar:events}` would be used for general information about the event entry (eg. event location, summary, start/end dates set in the entry), and `{exp:calendar:cal}` is used for most things related to *time* (eg. upcoming events, past events, events between X and Y, chronological order of events and their occurrences, etc).